# Which libraries have good implementations of Basis splines?

Tags: finite-element, libraries, basis-set, c, c++

I'm looking to use the finite element method with [B-splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-splines) as my function basis. Which C/C++ libraries have good B-spline support?

Specifically, I'm looking for an implementation of a stable algorithm, even if it's slow. I plan to precompute a lot of the inner products I need and store them in a file somewhere if the b-spline calculation gets slow enough to be bothersome.

Comment: I'm pointing this question to Nathan Collier, who has done some work using the fundamental PETSc data structures to implement b-splines as a basis in PETSc.  [Here's an example](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/ts/examples/tutorials/ex18.c.html). [Instructions for how to run the code](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/petsc-dev/2011-April/004824.html) (in a PETSc 3.2-p5 install).  This is early work, so there may be some rough edges.

Answer (score 5):

The Gnu Scientific Library (GSL) has an implementation of B-splines, and the documentation can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Basis-Splines.html). According to the documentation, GSL uses De Boor's algorithm, which is numerically stable.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at John Burkhardt's libraries at http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/
His code is LGPL licensed, as opposed to the GPL used by the Gnu Scientific Library.